# Joomla membership for old articles

Tags: joomla, membership

I would like my Joomla website to behave like this:

- All users can view new articles
- When new articles are published over sometime (say 1 week), they become
  old articles. (This part can be done
  manually, if there are no extension
  for it.)

Then,

- Normal users can only view the title of old articles. If they click them, they are asked to pay.
- Paid users can view old articles.
- All users can search against new and old articles. But as mentioned, only paid users can view old articles.

What kind of extensions do I need?
Thank you very much.

**Updated:**
I asked AEC (Account Expiration Control) support about my requirements. Here the reply I got:

> AEC is not an Access Restriction
>   component but a Membership Manager
>   that happens to be good at telling
>   other components what they should do.
>   Many users extend the Joomla
>   usergroups with components like
>   FlexiAccess, JACL or JUGA. With
>   extended usergroups (and, in this
>   case, Access Levels), you can restrict
>   access to articles, categories and
>   menu entries. I would advise that the
>   best idea might be to check out the
>   ACL components - AEC can cater to
>   pretty much all of them so that it's
>   more of a question whether the ACL
>   components can do what you want to
>   achieve.
>
> Also - archiving articles is
>   completely out of scope for AEC, so
>   you'd have to find out how to
>   accomplish this in your content
>   management.

**Updated 2:**
I think AEC might be the one I need.

Comment: I think you need to develop a custom extension for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Access Expiration Control](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/paid-membership-a-subscriptions/10723). You will have to do the follwing :

1. Create plans for your users and handle the plans ( Free, Monthly, Life time .. etc ) , the payment and the access control.
2. Create menu item for the archived articles.
3. Use ACE to make accessing this part of the site restricted to payed members.
4. Profit $$$

This is how I see how it could be done ... I've used on many sites but not for archived contents so I would recommend you contact the developers at their site and ask them about your case.